# Do negligible weights affect the control of a commercial aircraft?

Tags: commercial-aviation, weight-and-balance

I was watching a video and it said that switching seats on a commercial airplane would be fatal. "Switching of seats from the rear of the airplane to the front seats would result in probable accident". I think if a person weighing between 40-110kgs would be considered as of negligible weight relatively to the aircraft weight. 
Do such acts by passengers really affect the controls?

Reference:

Comment: A little bit of knowledge is a dangerous thing.  The short answer, based on the definition of "negligible", is no.

Comment: Welcome to aviation.SE.  One useful tip is to do a quick search before you post a question.  I clicked the tag you included (weight-and-balance) and not surprisingly found that several of the first 30 questions were asking basically the same thing.

Comment: By the definition of the word "negligible," negligible weights don't have any significant effect at all. When you wrote "negligible," did you mean to write "very small"?